# How to write this math expression in python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write this expression (x-3)(x+4) in python code, and cannot seem to get it correct. This code needs to be written as a single expression not given in lines.

Comment: Where is the value for x going to come from? stdin?

Answer (score 1):

Few programming languages allow omission of the multiplication operator when it is implied.

```
(x - 3) * (x + 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i still remember how to simplify

```
pow(x,2) + x - 12
```